# Execute public static method and catch return value, possible?

Tags: java, javafx

I call the static method `AddTask` from `ScanSystem()`. Here I want to declare a string variable, this seems to be working, but all the stuff inside `AddTask()` happens after finishing the method `ScanSystem()`, Why?
The UI wouldn't be updated after finishing `AddTask()`

### ScanSystem()

```
private void ScanSystem() {
    double startScanTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    //Preparing Event
    String startupTaskText = "System Scan has started!";
    double startUpProgress = 0;
    String taskID = App.AddTask(startupTaskText, startUpProgress);

    String [][] snapshotArray = manager.getSystemSnapshotsScanSystem(); //Get snapshots from Manager in Array
    tableScanSystemForSnapshots.setItems(getSnapshot(snapshotArray)); //push values to observableList

    double endScanTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String updateStartupTaskText = "System Scan finished in "+ ((endScanTime-startScanTime)/1000) + " Seconds";
    startUpProgress = 1;
    UpdateTask(taskID, updateStartupTaskText, startUpProgress);}
```

### AddTask()

```
public static String AddTask(String taskText, Double progress) {
    //TODO: do Add Task Logic here
    long longTaskId = System.currentTimeMillis(); //Define TaskID
    String taskId = ""+longTaskId;

    Label lblTaskEntry = new Label();
    lblTaskEntry.setText(taskText);
    lblTaskEntry.getStyleClass().add("TaskEntryLabel");
    lblTaskEntry.setId(taskId + "Label");

    Separator separatorTasks = new Separator();
    separatorTasks.setPrefWidth(230);

    ProgressIndicator piTaskEntry = new ProgressIndicator();
    piTaskEntry.getStyleClass().add("TaskEntryProgressIndicator");
    piTaskEntry.setId(taskId + "ProgressIndicator");
    if (progress != 0){
        piTaskEntry.setProgress(progress);
        piTaskEntry.setMaxSize(55, 55); // set maxsize of Progress Indicator if he has progress > 0 and Determinate
    }else {
        piTaskEntry.setMaxSize(35,35);//set maxsize for Progress Indicator if he has state of Indeterminate
    }

    HBox hBoxProgressPaneInnerTaskEntry = new HBox();
    hBoxProgressPaneInnerTaskEntry.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
    hBoxProgressPaneInnerTaskEntry.setId(taskId + "Hbox");
    hBoxProgressPaneInnerTaskEntry.getChildren().addAll(piTaskEntry, lblTaskEntry);
    vBoxProgressPaneInner.getChildren().add(0, separatorTasks);
    vBoxProgressPaneInner.getChildren().add(1, hBoxProgressPaneInnerTaskEntry);
    return taskId;
}
```

Comment: You get a taskId in ScanSystem right? when you say AddTask() happens after ScanSystem do you mean the task created in AddTask

Comment: Please use [proper naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java).

Comment: Yes, I create longTaskId as long in ScanSystem() and fill it with the system time. After that I set the ID of the FX components (Label and ProgressIndicator) to this ID, so i could acess it in UpdateTask(taskId, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be doing all this on the FX Application Thread. That thread is responsible for updating the UI, so no actual changes to the UI will happen until the entire `ScanSystem()` (sic) method is complete.

To fix this, you need to perform the long-running operation in a background thread, and schedule the incremental updates to the UI on the FX Application Thread using `Platform.runLater(...)`:

```
private void scanSystem() {
    new Thread(() -> {
        double startScanTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //Preparing Event
        String startupTaskText = "System Scan has started!";
        double startUpProgress = 0;
        String taskID = App.addTask(startupTaskText, startUpProgress);

        String [][] snapshotArray = manager.getSystemSnapshotsScanSystem(); //Get snapshots from Manager in Array
        tableScanSystemForSnapshots.setItems(getSnapshot(snapshotArray)); //push values to observableList

        double endScanTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String updateStartupTaskText = "System Scan finished in "+ ((endScanTime-startScanTime)/1000) + " Seconds";
        startUpProgress = 1;
        updateTask(taskID, updateStartupTaskText, startUpProgress);
    }).start();

}
```

and

```
public static String addTask(String taskText, Double progress) {
    //TODO: do Add Task Logic here
    long longTaskId = System.currentTimeMillis(); //Define TaskID
    String taskId = ""+longTaskId;

    Platform.runLater(() -> {

        Label lblTaskEntry = new Label();
        lblTaskEntry.setText(taskText);
        lblTaskEntry.getStyleClass().add("TaskEntryLabel");
        lblTaskEntry.setId(taskId + "Label");

        Separator separatorTasks = new Separator();
        separatorTasks.setPrefWidth(230);

        ProgressIndicator piTaskEntry = new ProgressIndicator();
        piTaskEntry.getStyleClass().add("TaskEntryProgressIndicator");
        piTaskEntry.setId(taskId + "ProgressIndicator");
        if (progress != 0){
            piTaskEntry.setProgress(progress);
            piTaskEntry.setMaxSize(55, 55); // set maxsize of Progress Indicator if he has progress > 0 and Determinate
        }else {
            piTaskEntry.setMaxSize(35,35);//set maxsize for Progress Indicator if he has state of Indeterminate
        }

        HBox hBoxProgressPaneInnerTaskEntry = new HBox();
        hBoxProgressPaneInnerTaskEntry.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        hBoxProgressPaneInnerTaskEntry.setId(taskId + "Hbox");
        hBoxProgressPaneInnerTaskEntry.getChildren().addAll(piTaskEntry, lblTaskEntry);
        vBoxProgressPaneInner.getChildren().add(0, separatorTasks);
        vBoxProgressPaneInner.getChildren().add(1, hBoxProgressPaneInnerTaskEntry);
    });

    return taskId;
}
```